# Mouse events not working in OpenLaszlo application

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, openlaszlo

I have designed a highlighter that works fine with html pages, but when I am trying to integrate with an OpenLaszlo application I am facing problem with the mouse events.....

The OpenLaszlo application has a button which on clicking activates the highlighter.The application has been deployed as a solo application and the function corresponding to the button has been written in the "index.html" file that is generated.

The button code defined in the Laszlo application is as follows :--

```
 <button name="Highlighter" onclick="highlightController()">Highlighter
            
                <method name="highlightController">
                    if(parent.check="false"){
                            this.setAttribute("check", true);
                            
                            if(this.check == true){
                                lz.Browser.loadJS('Highlight("true")');
                            }
                            else if(this.check == false){
                                lz.Browser.loadJS('Highlight("false")');
                            }
                    }
                </method>
  </button>
```

The corresponding button function is a follows:--

```
    function Highlight(check) {
        alert("button function");
        var cursor = {},
        divr = {},
        dragging = false,
        dv=document.createElement('div');
        dv.setAttribute('id',"maindiv");
        document.body.appendChild(dv);
        var maindiv=document.getElementById('maindiv');
    
    function maindivstart(a, b) {
    
        cursor.a = a;
        cursor.b = b;
        maindivposition();
        dragging = true;
        $('#maindiv').clone().insertAfter("#maindiv");
    
    }

    function maindivsize(a, b) {

        divr.left = a < cursor.a ? a : cursor.a;
        divr.top = b < cursor.b ? b : cursor.b;
        divr.width = Math.abs(a - cursor.a),
        divr.height = Math.abs(b - cursor.b);
        maindivposition();
        maindivresize();

    }

    function maindivend() {

        dragging = false;
    
    }

    function maindivposition() {

        maindiv.style.top = divr.top + 'px';
        maindiv.style.left = divr.left + 'px';

    }

    function maindivresize() {

        maindiv.style.width = divr.width + 'px';
        maindiv.style.height = divr.height + 'px';

    }

    window.onmousedown = ( function (e) {
   
        var a = e.clientX,
            b = e.clientY;
        e.preventDefault();
        maindivstart(a, b);

    });

    window.onmousemove = ( function (e) {
    
        var a = e.clientX,
            b = e.clientY;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (dragging) {
            maindivsize(a, b);
        }

    });

    window.onmouseup = ( function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        maindivend();
    
    });

}
```

The mouse events are not working... can anyone help?

Comment: Which OpenLaszlo version and runtime are you using?

Comment: openlaszlo version-4.9.0

Comment: And the runtime? SWF or DHTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MB24051988/6S5sV/7/

Comment: the above link shows how the actual thing should work..it's a html application

Comment: i am getting the alert message from the higlight function..

Answer (score 1):

When you have an application using the DHTML runtime, you can call any JavaScript function directly, no need go through lz.Browser.

```
<canvas>

  <!-- Calling the alert function from a DHTML OpenLaszlo app -->
  <button onclick="window.alert('Calling JS from OpenLaszlo')"
      text="Call some JS" />

</canvas>
```

If you want to compile for both runtimes, it's better to use lz.Browser:

```
<canvas>

  <button text="Call some JS">
    <handler name="onclick">
       lz.Browser.loadJS("alert('Calling JS from OpenLaszlo')");
    </handler>
  </button>

</canvas>
```

One possible source for a bug can be if the code embedding the OpenLaszlo application into an HTML page is not correct. The best way to deploy an application is to use the SOLO deployment tool (I'm assuming you have done that). In case something is not working, check the browser JavaScript error console for error messages. You can directly evaluate expression in the console as well. What happens if you type the following JavaScript expression into the console, while you have your application loaded:

```
lz.Browser.loadJS('alert("true")');
```

Do you see any error messages?